# How to build walkie talkie app through wifi or mobile data?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, call, voice

I want to build a function in my app. That should work like walkie talkie through mobile data or wifi.There will be a button that when they press it will send real time their voice to all logged in users IN THEIR GROUP and when they unpress it it stops, but I have no idea where to start with this. Like I know I probably need some server or something. Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a question that can be easily answered in the SO format. If you want to create that functionality yourself, you'd have to learn **a lot**. Start from some Android tutorial, there are plenty. If you are new to programming in general, forget mobile and learn to code for an easier platform first. If you expect someone at SO to give you ready to use code, that's unlikely, as this is a lot of work.

Comment: I'm not new in programming I just never worked with voice streaming and don't know where to start I didn't find anything, just wanted to know what i need to know for this to work. I can do -> record voice -> send file to cloud -> send from cloud to users -> play it. but this has too much delay. I want them to hear him speaking real time

Comment: Start by reading up on getting sound input from the microphone on Android. Class `android.media.AudioManager`.

Comment: Okay thanks...but record the voice isn't the problem.. problem is I need something that will constantly send the voice to users WHILE recording... some server that will proccess this and send/connect it to users and this is something i'm struggling with :D... something like Zello app doing if you know.

Comment: Read up on network communication in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not that hard to do. I've done this myself like 10 years ago. I say it's not hard because Android already includes the necessary APIs to make it simple enough.

First you need to understand two concepts:

1. VoIP
2. SIP protocol

Once you've got this, grab some example projects and read the APIs:

- SIP Demo / walkie talkie sample project: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo/src/com/example/android/sip/WalkieTalkieActivity.java
- SIP API:
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip Be aware that this has been deprecated in API level 31.

Note that to use SIP you need a couple of accounts with a SIP provider; you should be able to find free ones. Or you can also setup your own SIP server.

Hope this helps.